# Istio - subset propagation

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, istio, servicemesh

I'm using Istio with my application. The configuration for my app should be duplicated on each layer:

frontend-app pod => v1, v2

backend-app pod => v1, v2

and two similar external db schemas

I need to 2 versions of each pods, so I have v1,v2 subsets for frontend, v1,v2 subsets for backend and two db external schemas e.g d1,d2.

Correct results should be like:

v1 frontend -> v1 backend -> first db schema response

v2 fronted -> v2 backend -> second db schema response

Route is based on header as below:

```
kind: VirtualService
...
spec:
  hosts:
  - fronted-app-domain
  gateways:
  - frontend-app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        end-user:
          exact: jason
    route:
    - destination:
        host: frontend-app-sv
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: frontend-app-sv
        subset: v1
```

```
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: frontend-app-sv
spec:
  host: frontend-app-sv
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

```
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: backend-app-sv
spec:
  host: backend-app-sv
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

Additionally I have 4 deployments :
Frontend with versions v1, v2
Backend with versions v1, v2

Traffic for backend is routed and responses from dbs are displayed, but the results are displayed once from one database schema to another after requesting again. So my conclusion suggests that backend doesn't recognize subsets on this level. It causes cases like:

v1 frontend -> v1 backend -> first schema - ok

v1 frontend -> v2 backend -> second schema - :(

(end-user header) v2 frontend -> v2 backend -> second schema - ok

(end-user header) v2 frontend -> v1 backend -> first schema - :(

Do we have any mechanism in Istio to control cohesion of subsets between frontend and backend layers? On the Istio page examples we can find only simple situation with two version of first layer (v1, v2 on frontend, only single backend)

Comment: Which version of Istio did you use? Did you see [this page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/)? Using short names like this only works if the destination hosts and the virtual service are actually in the same Kubernetes namespace. Because using the Kubernetes short name can result in misconfigurations, we recommend that you specify fully qualified host names in production environments.

Comment: I use the newest Istio version. I saw the page with destination rules and all myconfiguration is in single namespace. The issue sitll exists. I think second destination rule doesn't know context but how I can change the config. Versions v1, v2 are added in every required places @mikołajGłodziak

Comment: Does frontend call the backend just via the hostname `backend-app-sv`? In that case you would need to add a virtual service for the backend that matches on the source label and routes to backend v1 or v2 depending on the source labels.